# Deploying React native app with node server to the store

Tags: node.js, react-native, heroku, websocket, expo

I feel like I have exhausted all possible searches and documentation trying to figure this out.  I have a React native app which runs perfectly locally with a node server with websockets, I will like to know steps on how I could deploy this app to the store. I understand the server has to be hosted for example on heroku, but the workaround of the whole process from local server to heroku, then AppStore still confuses me. I will appreciate any suggestions, or clarification on how I could achieve this(deploying server and connecting to React native). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Host your Node.js server;
2. Use the remote server's endpoint on the app;

This can be useful to have a dynamic endpoint (dev and production env):

```
const endpoint = __DEV__ ? 'http://localhost:8080' : 'https://myServer/';
```

After your app get published on App Store it will communicate with remote server.